# real time validation in jquery on keypress , keyup and keydown

Tags: jquery

here problem is firstname and lastname performing validation together please sort out when i click on first name textfield validation should check firstname only not the last name .............................................................................................................

```
<html>
<head>
<title>s1</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body  {font-family:"Trebuchet MS",verdana;width:800px;}
    #info {color:#008000;font-weight:bold; }
    #age  {width: 40px;}
    .error_msg { color: red;}
    #content{ color: red; }
    span.error {font-size: 11px; color: #D8000C; }
    .emsg{ color: red; }
    .hidden {  visibility:hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="forms1">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Please fill the information</strong></legend>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="fname"  class="required name" /> 
                             <span class="emsg hidden">Please Enter a Valid Name</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="lname" class="required name"  />
                             <span class="emsg hidden">Please Enter a Valid Name</span>
                        </td>           
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="age" maxlength="3"  class="required age" />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="address"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save" id="save" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<p id="content"></p>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var $regexname=/^[A-z]+$/;

$('.name').on('keypress keydown keyup',function()
{
    if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) 
    {
       // there is a mismatch, hence show the error message

         $('.emsg').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.emsg').show();

   }
  else
    {
      // else, do not display message

       $('.emsg').addClass('hidden');
   }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: becoz you are using class name to validate function and both element having same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
    $('.name').on('blur',function(){
      if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) 
      {
          // there is a mismatch, hence show the error message

           $(this).parent().find('.emsg').removeClass('hidden');
           $(this).parent().find('.emsg').show();

      }else{
             // else, do not display message

            $('.emsg').addClass('hidden');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var $regexname=/^[A-z]+$/;

$('#fname').on('keypress keydown keyup',function()
{
    if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) 
    {
       // there is a mismatch, hence show the error message

         $('.emsg').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.emsg').show();

   }
  else
    {
      // else, do not display message

       $('.emsg').addClass('hidden');
   }
});
$('#lname').on('keypress keydown keyup',function()
{
    if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) 
    {
       // there is a mismatch, hence show the error message

         $('.emsg').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.emsg').show();

   }
  else
    {
      // else, do not display message

       $('.emsg').addClass('hidden');
   }
});
});
</script>
```